# Keep position in scrollviewer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

My problem is that I have a databinded ItemsControl with some data presented in a list and user can scroll up and down.

When adding new items to the list (i.e. user refreshes the list), the scroll position moves according to however many new items there are. Is there a way to keep the scroll position upon adding new items?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just store the scroll-position and set the scroll-position back manually after the refresh?

Comment: if for example the user is at the top of the list, the offset will be 0. When new items are added the offset will still be 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the TombStone Helper project on Codeplex in the ListBoxTombstoner.cs class [1] you will find code which allows you to get at the underlying ScrollViewer for the listbox and get its VerticalOffset property.

You will then be able to manipulate this property however you want - either adding to it if you want the scroll position to move as you add items, or keep it the same.

[1] http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e737b2a34421#TombstoneHelper%2fListBoxTombstoner.cs

Comment: I know what I need to access etc but it's not as simple as that, however I have found the solution and will post example code here when I get the chance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on the ListBox

Comment: This will only work with a ListBox and requires the SelectedItem to be set, the SelectedItem may not always be the Item at the top of the current ListBox view

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all items are of a fixed height you should be able to adjust the the ScrollOffset after the addition-being sure to take the number of added items into consideration.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but each item is a varying height as there is text which changes in length for each item. Maybe I will have to calculate the total height of the new items somehow and adjust the scroll offset by that...